# How to access a column name at run time in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to write a function pmean (directory, pollutant) where
directory <- is the location of the data frame and
pollutant <- is one of the column name in data frame.

directory and pollutant both of them are strings

I was able to load the data frame in R using

```
x <- directory  
x1 <- read.csv(x)
```

Now I want find mean of 'pollutant' column name which was passed by the user in the function. I try to use the same by

```
y<- pollutant
x2 <- mean(x1$y)
```

But I am getting output as     NULL here.
How can I access the column names and apply some functions on it?

Comment: Perhaps `mean(x1[,y])`

Comment: It's not very clear, but maybe you also need to put `pollutant` in quotes? something like `y<- "pollutant"` and then use @akruns suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
x<-df[,columnName]
```

format to access individual columns of a data frame.
So in your case

```
mean(x1[,"pollutant"])
```

will get you required ans.

Also see basics of data access on quickR or CRAN site for more related solutions.